# Running PHP Contact Form on EC2 for S3-Hosted Website

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I'm a fairly novice-level programmer, so please excuse any (very) banal mistakes in the following.

I'm currently creating a personal branding website of a few HTML5/CSS3 pages hosted on Amazon S3, including a contact page. My contact form currently directs to a PHP page on an (Amazon Linux) EC2 instance that I have setup as a LAMP server by following [AWS's guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) and some (kind of fun) trial-and-error. My intention is to get this PHP form to splice whatever information the contact puts in into a MySQL database hosted as a separate (AWS-based) RDS instance.

While I know that there's many more simple ways out there (a mailto action, etc.), I've been trying my hardest to get this to work, but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. My form will redirect to the PHP page perfectly fine, but no returns occur nor data put into the DB. Essentially, I just get a flat white page.

Must I set up the database on the same LAMP server as the PHP redirect, or is there something completely wonky in my code?

I've posted my PHP code below as well as the Contact page's form HTML. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

**PHP Code (contact.php):**

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("[Instance Public IP]:[Port #]", "[Username]", "[Password]", "[Database Name]")

if($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect." . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$contact_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Name']);
$contact_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['E-Mail']);
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Subject']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Message']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (contact_name, contact_email, subject, message) VALUES ('$contact_name','$contact_email', '$subject', '$message')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Thank you! Your message has been sent successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Unable to send successfully." .
    mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**HTML Code (contact.html):**

```
            <form action="[contact.php URL]" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="Name"><b>Name:</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="Name" autofocus required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="E-Mail"><b>E-Mail:</b></label>
                <input type="email" id="E-Mail" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Subject"><b>Subject:</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="Subject" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Message"><b>Message:</b></label>
                <textarea id="Message" required>Please write your inquiry here.</textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I have replaced all [generic tags] in my production code with the requisite username(s), password(s), etc.

Comment: you have to add a `name` attribute in your html input. For example instead of `<input type="email" id="E-Mail" required />` you should write `<input type="email" id="E-Mail" name="E-Mail" required />`

read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Hi @Maz; thank you for the very quick reply as well as the link! I've gone ahead and edited my HTML to use your recommendation, but I am unfortunately still stuck with the same issue. I'm able to pull up the AMI test page, so I know my EC2 instance is publicly accessible, but my PHP isn't even returning an error code... Hrm, I'll try and delve into these docs more, thank you again!

Comment: in your contact.php page do this: `var_dump($_POST)`. What is the result ?

Comment: Also just noticed you have syntax errors in code `echo "ERROR: Unable to send successfully." .` use `;` instead of `.`

And `$link = mysql_connect("[Instance Public IP]:[Port #]", "[Username]", "[Password]", "[Database Name]")` semicolon `;` at the end of the line

Comment: @Maz, my apologies for the late response. Thank you so much for your help! My stupid syntax errors were the root of the problem here, so now I've at least got a working PHP page on my hands. It looks like my DB connection is a little wonky, however, so I've still a bit of work to do. At least I'm getting an error-return, now! ("ERROR: Could not connect.") I'll be diving into the RDS settings, but for now this saved my bacon. Thanks again!

Comment: Cheers mate. happy to help and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was:

- Syntax errors
- HTML input name attribute is needed for posting form in php

Some suggestions:

- Use a IDE that can auto detect your syntax errors.
- Start learning simple debugging tricks like `var_dump`
- Dive into xdebug

Happy coding :)